# How puts variable in iterators code Ruby

Tags: ruby, iterator, puts

How puts variable in iterators code Ruby
EX: `(1,2,3).select { |v| puts v > 2}`

Comment: What? Could you rephrase?

Comment: You want to write `[1,2,3].select { |v| puts v > 2}´, which works... ?

Comment: Are you asking how to do that. Or you know how to do that, but you want to know how it works?

Comment: It's a bit harsh to downvote someone's first question when it looks like English isn't their first language. This isn't a competition it's a _community_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems syntax error, I think you want something like this

```
[1,2,3].select { |v| puts v > 2 }
```

output would be :

```
false

false

true
```

Take a look [here](http://codepad.org/Cxwn20DG)